# A C# hangman game

Tags: c#, object-oriented, game, hangman

I made this c# hangman game...

I would like to know what you all think about it.

This is a pretty basic but still gets the job done let me know what you think.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace idontknow
{
    class thehangedman
    {
        public bool status = true;
        public int turnsleft;
        public string strdisplay;
        private string originalstr;
        public thehangedman(string oristr,int turnsava)
        {
            this.originalstr = oristr.ToLower();
            this.strdisplay = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", oristr.Length));
            this.turnsleft = turnsava;
        }
        public string attemptchar(char attempt)
        {

            if(this.originalstr.Contains(attempt))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.originalstr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (this.originalstr[i] == attempt)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.strdisplay);
                        sb[i] = attempt;
                        this.strdisplay = sb.ToString();
                    }
                       
                }
                if (this.originalstr == this.strdisplay)
                {
                    this.status = false;
                    return "GG kid you won";
                }
                return "You found a char";
            }
            else
            {
                if(this.turnsleft == 0)
                {
                    this.status = false;
                    return "No attemps left originalstring = " + this.originalstr;
                }
                return "Char not in string attemps left = " + this.turnsleft--;
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Game1 = new thehangedman(Console.ReadLine(),6);
            while(Game1.status){
                Console.WriteLine(Game1.strdisplay);
                Console.WriteLine(Game1.attemptchar(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common C# naming conventions are to have class/struct fields, method parameters and local variable in camelCase and namespaces, type names, property, and method names in PascalCase. Additionally, field names are often introduced with an underscore.

Example:

```cs
namespace MyName.Games.Hangman
{
    class TheHangedMan
    {
        private string _originalString;

        public string AttemptCharacter(char attempt)
        {
            string localVariable;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Fields (i.e., class or struct variables) should be private or protected. (Protected means available to derived classes.)

Expose them through properties. If they are initialized through an initializer in the declaration or within the constructor, they can be read-only. This makes clear that they will not and should not change during the whole lifetime of the game.

```cs
private readonly string _originalString;
```

`strdisplay` is exposed. You could implement it like this

```cs
private _displayText; // A better name than strdisplay!
public string DisplayText { get { return _displayText; } }

// or with the newer syntax
public string DisplayText => _displayText;
```

You can also use an auto property which inherently creates an invisible field:

```cs
public string DisplayText { get; private set; }
```

You can assign it a value in the class with `DisplayText = "value";` but you can only read it from outside.

---

You do not need the `this` keyword. E.g.

```cs
private readonly string _originalString;
private int _turnsLeft;

public TheHangedMan(string originalString, int turnsAvailable)
{
    _originalString = originalString;
    _turnsLeft = turnsAvailable;
}
```

---

When you are writing the code, it seems to be a good idea to use abbreviations for identifiers, but when looking at your code six month later and for other people, this makes reading difficult. `turnsava`: it took me a while to understand it. Is it something with "turn" and "save"? Oh no, it is "turns available"!

Common abbreviations and math symbols are okay (like `i` for the loop index). Also, sometimes the meaning of an abbreviation can be inferred easily from the context. Especially when used only locally. Like in the case of `var sb = new StringBuilder(DisplayText);`.

Good names are important for the understanding of the code.

`bool status`. What does this mean? `true` = there is a status, `false` there is no status? Obviously not. Better `_isRunning`.

Another option is to have the status be an enum. E.g.

```cs
enum GameStatus
{
    Running,
    Won,
    Lost
}
```

Then the name "status" makes sense

```cs
public GameStatus Status { get; private set; }
```

---

One empty line between type declarations (between the two classes), between field declarations and constructors/methods and between methods/constructors enhances readability.

---

lines like `Console.WriteLine(Game1.attemptchar(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));` are compact but often difficult to read. Using a temporary variable gives you the opportunity to use descriptive names for intermediate results:

```cs
char attempt = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string message = game.AttemptCharacter(attempt);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

---

There are always many ways to solve problems. Here are some alternatives (which does not mean that your solution was not good):

`new String(' ', originalString.Length);` instead of `String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", originalString.Length))`.

Instead of creating a `StringBuilder` each time for the manipulation of the display string, you could create one as class field

```cs
private readonly StringBuilder _displayTextBuilder;
```

and then dynamically create the display string from it when needed

```cs
public string DisplayText => _displayTextBuilder.ToString();
```

Note that the `StringBuilder` can be read-only because it is a reference type. Here `readonly` means that you cannot replace it by another instance or by `null`. It does not apply to its fields (i.e., its content).

This reduces updating a character to the one-liner `_displayTextBuilder[i] = attempt;`.

But since the length of the display string is constant, we can simply store it as character array `char[]` (this is the solution I have chosen).

Just take the first character of the string with `Console.ReadLine()[0]` instead of `Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`

---

My attempt to write it better:

```cs
using System;

namespace MyName.Games.Hangman
{
    class TheHangedMan
    {
        private readonly string _originalString;
        private readonly char[] _displayChars;
        public int _turnsLeft;

        public TheHangedMan(string originalString, int turnsAvailable)
        {
            _originalString = originalString.ToLower();
            _turnsLeft = turnsAvailable;
            _displayChars = new String(' ', originalString.Length).ToCharArray();
        }

        public bool IsRunning { get; private set; } = true;

        public string DisplayText => new String(_displayChars);

        public string AttemptCharacter(char attempt)
        {
            if (_originalString.Contains(attempt)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < _originalString.Length; i++) {
                    if (_originalString[i] == attempt) {
                        _displayChars[i] = attempt;
                    }
                }
                if (_originalString == DisplayText) {
                    IsRunning = false;
                    return "GG kid you won";
                }
                return "You found a char";
            } else {
                if (_turnsLeft == 0) {
                    IsRunning = false;
                    return "No attemps left originalstring = " + _originalString;
                }
                return "Char not in string attemps left = " + _turnsLeft--;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            var game = new TheHangedMan(inputString, 6);
            while (game.IsRunning) {
                Console.WriteLine(game.DisplayText);
                char attempt = Console.ReadLine()[0];
                string message = game.AttemptCharacter(attempt);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But there is always something to be improved... maybe `GuessCharacter` instead of `AttemptCharacter`... it's up to you!

See also: [The Boy Scout Rule](https://www.matheus.ro/2017/12/11/clean-code-boy-scout-rule/)